# Swing controls are not visible

Tags: java, swing, controls

Swing controls are not visible.It displays a Grey screen without any components in it,Same thing is happening with awt?

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class s1 extends JFrame {

JLabel l1, l2;
JTextField t2;
JButton b1, b2;
JPanel p1;

public s1() {


    setTitle("Login Window");`setting title for the Window `
    setBounds(200, 200, 350, 150); `setting boundations for window`
    p1 = new JPanel();
```

Label not displayed`

```
l1 = new JLabel("User Name");
getContentPane().add(p1);
setSize(350, 150);
setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new s1();

}
}
```

Comment: You never add your label. You only add an empty `JPanel` to your `JFrame`

Answer (score 1):

Your JLabel has been created, but not added to any component, so it can't be visible:

```
p1.add(l1);
```

Assuming you wanted it to be displayed in your JPanel.